# Can PhoneGap work with local SQLite3 databases?

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I was wondering if PhoneGap can work with local SQLite3 databases and what level of SQLite3 support it has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya it does work, you can use either of following:
It's important to remember that PhoneGap is web apps packaged in a browser component. Everything that applies to mobile WebKit will apply to PhoneGap as well, and the environment in PhoneGap is also very similar to opening an HTML-file in a desktop browser.

Web SQL Database:
http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/

PhoneGap SQLite Plugin:
https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin

Comment: I see. Are there any size limitations? The W3C Spec mentions size limitations. I'm not after Gigabytes, but anything under 100 MB is depressing.

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap works very well with local SQLite3 database.

check out this link for tutorial http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/07cf9f48e3cd0663?pli=1